# Check if current element has a children with class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, children

I would like to check if a element has a children with a class.

So I used:

```
$('input:checkbox, input:radio').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).children().hasClass('sub-question')) {
        alert('Yes');
    }
    else {
        alert('No');
    }
});
```

My HTML is the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Item A
        <input type="radio">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Item B
        <input type="radio">
    </label>
    <div class="row sub-question">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="container_radio">Sub level 1
                <input type="radio">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you please help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: `<input>` elements cannot have any children since they are self-closing tags. You would need to traverse up to some parent element (eg `.form-group`) before checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to context of the checkbox/radio button. You need to traverse to closest form-group and then use `.find()` selector with length to check if element exists :

```
if($(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').length > 0) {
    alert('Yes');
}
else {
    alert('No');
}
```

Comment: Why a down vote for this proposed solution? Does it means that using `.find` is not a good approach here?

Comment: @popol Yes, that's what it means. In the context that you are using it on the `input` elements which are firing off the `event`. See comment by `Phil`, it will give you the correct direction.

Comment: @RyanWilson `.find()` seems an ok approach to me, provided you're looking within the appropriate element

Comment: @Phil I agree and I agree with your comment above. I modified my comment to reflect that.

Comment: My bad, I thought `this`  refers to context of container and not the element. updated answer now.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, sorry I just noted that under `.sub-question` I have new radio button. With your code actually, when I clicked on these new sub radio button, it hides the `.sub-question`. Do you know how can I solve this? I have updated the question the top. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @popol: Can you update the click handler code that is responsible for hiding element

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, sorry I don't catch your question. I've actually `el = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question');` and after the condition `if(el.length > 0) { el.css('display', 'block'); }`.

Comment: Yes sure but when I clicked on one radio button in this sub-level, it closed the main radio button group.

Comment: Can you explain what exact behaviour should happen?

Comment: If I click on a radio which is under a `div.sub-menu` it should not hide this current `div.sub-menu`. The rest is perfect. only this point is not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can then only attach the event to first level element. something like this `$('.form-group > label').find(' > input:checkbox, > input:radio').on('click', function() {`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, hum I think it's not working at 100%: https://jsfiddle.net/nefosdvx/1/.

Answer (score 1):

In your example any of the elements selected by `'input:checkbox, input:radio'` has children.

You can do something like traversing up through its ancestors until find the `.sub-question` element using the [.closet](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method

```js
$('input:checkbox, input:radio').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').length > 0) {
        alert('Yes');
    }
    else {
        alert('No');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, I found your answer is too close than the Milind Anantwar ones. But I would like to  thank your to help me.

Comment: I was too slow to posting it :)